# What ciphers supported by Java client when connecting via SSLSocketFactory?

Tags: java-8, sslsocketfactory

How possible to get the list of supported ciphers by Java **client** when I create a connection using `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`?

We use Java 8.

I have checked in `jre/lib/security/java.security`.
I can find only list of disabled ciphers.

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DES, DESede, 3DES, SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
    EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
```

Where can I find the list of supported ciphers?

**Note:** I do know how to get the list of supported ciphers by Java **server**.
I want to understand how to get list of supported ciphers by Java **client**.

**Added**

The list returned by `getSupportedCipherSuites` is the following:

```
0 = "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
1 = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
2 = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
3 = "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
4 = "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
5 = "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
6 = "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
7 = "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
8 = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
9 = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
10 = "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
11 = "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
12 = "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
13 = "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
14 = "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
15 = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
16 = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
17 = "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
18 = "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
19 = "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
20 = "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
21 = "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
22 = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
23 = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
24 = "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
25 = "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
26 = "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
27 = "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
28 = "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
29 = "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
30 = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
31 = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
32 = "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
33 = "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
34 = "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
35 = "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
36 = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
37 = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
38 = "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
39 = "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
40 = "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
41 = "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
42 = "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"
```

Comment: What is the result you get with `getDefaultCipherSuites()` and `getSupportedCipherSuites()`?

Comment: I have added the list to the question. 
Is this the answer?

Comment: @Michael: keep in mind that the exact list of supported and/or enabled cipher suites can depend on the configuration and/or version/build of your JDK. Security updates, for example, might disable or add cipher suites to this list. So there is single list that is always applicable to all Java 8 installations.

Comment: It depends on your exact java release. They added new ciphers in `1.8.0_221`

Comment: Hi @Progman, do you want to answer the question? I will be able to accept your answer.

Comment: @Michael You can answer your own question if you have found yourself a solution for the problem. You can write in detail what the solution is.